# Font-Awesome Showing FL as icon with SASS

Tags: sass, font-awesome

Using Font-Awesome 5 and following the usage docs on their website I set up a little .scss test.  The problem I am running into is that the icon (which should show a magnifying glass) show "fl" instead.

```
@import "./scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "./scss/fa-solid.scss";
.test{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: purple; 
}
.test:before{
    @include fa-icon;
    @extend .fab;   
    content: fa-content($fa-var-search);
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Verified the _variables.scss is pointing to the proper web folder and that the resources are loading.

Any help would greatly be apppreciated.

Comment: Do you load font files? https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/web-fonts-with-css/webfonts

Comment: Confirmed the font files are loading.

Comment: Only used font awesome once, but are you defining font awesome as the font anywhere? ie: font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome